# Create Lucene index with only one segment

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

How can I create Lucene index that will have only one segment (without using force merge)
I have more than enough RAM so I have tried using 1.5GB buffer size for mucj smaller index of up to 64-128MB but still having 5-10 segments at the end of indexing.
What can i do about it?

```
public static final double DEFAULT_RAM_BUFFER_SIZE_MB_STORE = 1536.;

...

final File file = new File(pathIndex);
final Path path = file.toPath();
final Directory index = ControlObjectsLuceneIndex.createDirectory(path, file);
final IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
indexWriterConfig.setRAMBufferSizeMB(defaultRamBufferSizeMb);
indexWriterConfig.setSimilarity(_ekspertSimilarity);
indexWriterConfig.setUseCompoundFile(false);
return new IndexWriter(index, indexWriterConfig);
```

Comment: why do you need 1 segment? could you show the code that doing actual adding docs?

Comment: I have some complicated batch searches to analyze date that works quite faster when all documents are in one segments. Code for adding docs is creating document with a lot of fields and then indes.Writer.addDocument(document);

Comment: You still could force merge to 1 segment, right?

Comment: Yes I can. Force merge works but it is quite time expensive too. I want to use my RAM resources to buffer data and write into one segment for probably fastest process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A flush is triggered when there are enough added documents since the
>   last flush. Flushing is triggered either by RAM usage of the documents
>   (see `IndexWriterConfig.setRAMBufferSizeMB(double)`) or the number of
>   added documents (see `IndexWriterConfig.setMaxBufferedDocs(int)`).

This means, that if you want to prevent flushing - you need to set high limit on both those values, to ensure that both number of added documents and RAM usage will be less than your limits.

Another approach could be to pass `IndexWriterConfig.DISABLE_AUTO_FLUSH` in `setMaxBufferedDocs` or in `setRAMBufferSizeMB`
 to prevent triggering a flush due to number of buffered documents or RAM usage. Note, that however you couldn't set both values to be `DISABLE_AUTO_FLUSH` and most likely you should be able to figure out your number of documents easier, than amount of RAM

Also, make sure that your usage of IndexWriter is in single thread only (or properly synchronized)

Source: https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html

Comment: Can't set bot max to DISABLE_AUTO_FLASH
I have tried (again) to set max buffered docs to max value but flush still happens and segments created. Maybe multiple threads have something with it?!

        indexWriterConfig.setMaxBufferedDocs(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        indexWriterConfig.setRAMBufferSizeMB(IndexWriterConfig.DISABLE_AUTO_FLUSH);
//        indexWriterConfig.setMaxBufferedDocs(IndexWriterConfig.DISABLE_AUTO_FLUSH);

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer you couldn't set both

Comment: Hm app created multiple segments but got out of memory after some time. 16GB ram for 4GB of indexes. Need to investigate and optimize more or try with smaller data set

Comment: Nope. I have tried this with 3 smaller indexes to avoid OutOfMemory.
Index 1 (5MB) ends with only one segment.
Index 2 (20MB) ends with 4 segments.
Index 3 (250MB) ends with 3 segments.

Comment: When i make adding documents to writer synchronized then this setMaxBufferedDocs with max value provides one segment after all!! So this is proper solution but must be single threaded or synchronized.
Strange enough with setRAMBufferSizeMB I can't get this one segment no mater how high ram value I use ... Still experimenting but Mysterion take you for your help and pointers!

Comment: I will add this as a remark, yes IndexWriter could be not thread safe

Comment: I think IndexWriter is thread safe but when using in multiple threads produces multiple segments to index as faster it can.